# Storing database json file in optimal way for react native app

Tags: json, firebase, react-native, redux, react-native-flatlist

I’m using react native, redux and firebase and I have a 1 MB database export that contains food nutritional information from the Canadian Nutrition File database.

This data will never change and is used in a FlatList users can search and import from.

What’s the optimal way for me to store this for my users to access as fast as possible when searching?

I am thinking of simply including the json file with my other source files and calling it from there using require.

But since I have firebase and redux all setup I wondered if it made more sense for whatever reason to consider those options instead.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Importing from file would be the best solution as far as i know. If you store the data in redux store it won`t be cleared from memory until you kill the app. If you store it in a file you can import wherever your want and when the component is unmounted, whatever you`ve imported will be cleared from memory.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are already using redux, i'd go for adding the json content to the store on app init/mount so you can get it easily from everywhere.

Another options i'd consider:

1. Import, parse & render the JSON file stactically on runtime (as it never changes);
2. Use the AsyncStorage to make it available in local database but outsite the redux store thing.